# Fetching only one href within a subclass

Tags: python, selenium

When I iterate a class, get all href of the webpage. Instead I need the one I am interested in.

Source code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 product-item-image ">
    <a href="/venta/departamento/vallenar-atacama/4431575-centro-vallenar-uda?tp=2&amp;op=1&amp;iug=25&amp;ca=3&amp;ts=1&amp;mn=2&amp;or=&amp;sf=1&amp;sp=0&amp;at=0&amp;i=0">
        <img src="https://image.portalinmobiliario.cl/Portal/Propiedades/4431575_jxsysazc3fu_h100.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Scraping code

```
linkss = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.col-sm-3.product-item-image ')
el = []
for fotos in linkss:
    for elem in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a"):
        el.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
print(el)
```

This code is getting all the links of the webpage. Expecting only the one href under the class col-sm-3 product-item-image.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below line

```
for fotos in linkss:
    for elem in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a"):
```

to

```
for fotos in linkss:
    for elem in fotos.find_elements_by_xpath("./a"):
```

You are getting all links as your script is finding for all element with tag `a` rather finding with in the `fotos` element.

Comment: Get the same result, ALL the links in the webpage :/

Comment: can you please try with the updated answer. Make sure you are usig `./` in xpath.

Answer (score 0):

But I am trying to find  WIHTIN the class. this is why did not expect ALL...
I will try your tips, will see ;) Thx, btw

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".col-sm-3.product-item-image > a")

Now I get JUST what I need!! ;)